# Looking for a way to access c++ objects in C as if I was in c++

Tags: c, linux

I have a few ideas:

`char* test = "testInteger(5).workOnReturn("doIt")[10]"`

`int ret = execute(test);`

What if I use the 'extern' keyword?

Suppose I have a whole bunch of C++ implementations and classes.
Couldn't I just define the same things in C with 'extern' and provide a dummy implementation and on runtime, it would access the C++ library with the actual implementation?

Comment: Provide a C API for your C++ functions.

Comment: yeah but that will be huge. The point is that the c++ api is nice to work with and the C API would be 100+ separate functions

Comment: That's the thing with C. It doesn't have classes. Note that you can use `extern "C"` in C++, but there's no equivalent in C. If you can't use C++ in your application and your library is only available in C++ you're screwed.

Comment: You could take the old-school C-API-based COM approach, but honestly, I would not wish that on my worst enemy (well... maybe my *worst* enemy).

Comment: The problem is that C++ doesn't have standardised ABI, so each compiler is free to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could customize your GCC compiler (e.g. with a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension) to produce somehow a C interface to your library (perhaps by annotating relevant C++ functions with your own `#pragma`-s ....)

But your question is too vague to get a more precise answer.

What is your C++ library, how should it be used in C++?

Look at how other C++ libraries interface to *C*; e.g. look inside the source code of [PPL](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/)

Comment: I want to wrap: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Dynamic.md

Comment: Why? That library is pretty C++ 2011 specific. Can't you use something else in your *C* code? Or switch to a dynamically typed scripting language (Python, Lua...) and perhaps code some extensions to it.... I feel your approach and design are wrong. Or use perhaps the `GValue` from GTK

Comment: If I'm going to use a crappy C api, you are right: I could just as well use any c json library. But the point is that this looks very nice to use. The reason I don't want to switch to scripting languages are too many to enumerate. I could switch to C#, but I really like C and I have a whole toolchain built up in C.

Comment: It is nice to use with C++2011 (and its limited type inference using `auto`). If you had to use it even with C++2003, it would be ugly. And even more ugly from C. So consider using some other "dynamic type" package, like GValue from GTK (in C), or Python's values.

Comment: I already have dynamic types, they are void* and C11 _generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C++ from C, it can be done only in an *extremely* limited way, and as far as the C++ code is explicitly built for it (that means basically throwing away most for what makes C++ C++). Won't happen in your case.

Your ways out are to just use C++ or get a library for C. Anything else will hurt too much to make any sense.